# return max purchase from column and group by country?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am looking to group by country and find the max purchase
related to that country.

```
SELECT 
    country , 
    customer_name, 
    total_purchased
FROM total
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

output:

```
    country       customer_name     total_purchased
   Australia     Diego Gutiérrez      39.6
   Australia      Mark Taylor         81.18
   Austria        Astrid Gruber       69.3
   Belgium        Daan Peeters        60.3899999
   Brazil        Alexandre Rocha      69.3
   Brazil        Eduardo Martins      60.39
```

I am looking for a way to return the best customer of the country. Best customer means the person of the country who spend more money.

Eg: In australia there are two person I want the table with one australia and a customer with max purchase. How can I do it? I tried but I couldn't figure out a way so far.

Desired output:

```
   country       customer_name     total_purchased
   Australia      Mark Taylor         81.18
   Austria        Astrid Gruber       69.3
   Belgium        Daan Peeters        60.3899999
   Brazil        Eduardo Martins      60.39
```

Comment: The last 3 questions under this tag all suffer from the same omission, which I admit does make me question whether it's me, and not all of you, that's at fault here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of SQL are you using but analytics functions can help you although are not available in old MySQL versions.
If you CAN use analytics functions, something like this might work:

```
SELECT country, 
    customer_name, 
    total_purchased
FROM (
SELECT 
    country, 
    customer_name, 
    total_purchased,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITIONED BY country ORDER BY total_purchased DESC) as rank
FROM total
) a
WHERE rank = 1
```

If you can't use analytics functions you can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.country, 
    a.customer_name, 
    a.total_purchased
FROM total a
JOIN (
SELECT 
    country, 
    MAX(total_purchased) AS max_purchased
FROM total
GROUP BY country
) b
ON a.country = b.country
AND a.total_purchased = b.max_purchased
```

This query should have the expected result. In case 2 customers have the same total_purchased value. The result will show both customers.

Comment: this code throws an error. I'm using sqlite3. I tried many codes but I couldn't return max price per country

Comment: @sai_636, I'm not familiar with SQLite but I think it does not support the analytics functions. Can you share the error? I've updated the answer anyway so it should work with SQLite

Comment: Thank you! That second code worked. Can you explain the code a bit?